# synchronize Outlook tasks with MS project

Tags: outlook, ms-project

I'm planning a project using MS project. then I send the different tasks to my collaborators directly to their outlook as outlook tasks.
Now, I want to synchronize outlook with MS project i.e each time the collborator modify a task on his outlook (when he puts it as done/finished..), this infos will be directly updated in my MS project. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There was an addin for this WAY back in like 2002 produced by Microsoft for the Japanese market but it never really took off and I think it was killed in like 2005. 
If you are using Project Online Im almost sure you can link tasks to Planner. That might do what you need.

Comment: Hi , actually I'm using desktop versions